# What value should I use? (Choose to display table data or not upon this variable)

Tags: php, mysql, variables

**form1.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die ("Couldn't Connect To Server");
$query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db1";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("db1", $connection)
or die ("Couldn't Select Database");
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (fname VARCHAR(20), lname VARCHAR(20), mail VARCHAR(20))";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
function insertvalues (){if ( isset ($_POST['fname']{0}, $_POST['lname']{0}, $_POST['mail']{0}) ){
   $query = "INSERT INTO table1 (fname, lname, mail) VALUES ('".$_POST[fname]."', '".$_POST[lname]."', '".$_POST[mail]."')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
}
else{
   echo "No Values Entered. Please Press Back In Your Browser And Enter Some Values.";
}}
$value1 = "";

if isset($value1) {$query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
    echo "<TABLE BORDER = '1'>";
    echo "<TR>";
    echo "<TH>First Name</TH><TH>Last Name</TH><TH>Mail</TH>";
    echo "</TR>";    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
echo "<TR>";
echo "<TD>", $row['fname'], "</TD><TD>",
$row['lname'], "</TD><TD>",
$row['mail'], "</TD>";
echo "</TR>";  
     }
    echo "</TABLE>";}

    else {
        echo "<BR>No Table".
    }

    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

I'm contemplating on what to put inside `$value1`. How do I check if"No Values Entered. Please Press Back In Your Browser And Enter Some Values." error was shown, and if it was, do not display the table?

Comment: "How do I check if the first part of the script gave "No values or entered or the values were inserted into the DB?" Can you clean this question up a bit? Right now it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen-Please explain? Not sure I understand what you mean...   @user151841-I'll rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you asked for?

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die ("Couldn't Connect To Server");
$query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db1";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("db1", $connection)
or die ("Couldn't Select Database");
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (fname VARCHAR(20), lname VARCHAR(20), mail VARCHAR(20))";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());


function insertvalues (){if ( isset ($_POST['fname']{0}, $_POST['lname']{0}, $_POST['mail']{0}) ){
   $query = "INSERT INTO table1 (fname, lname, mail) VALUES ('".$_POST[fname]."', '".$_POST[lname]."', '".$_POST[mail]."')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());

return true;
}
else{
   echo "No Values Entered. Please Press Back In Your Browser And Enter Some Values.";
   return false;
}}


$value1 = insertvalues();

if isset($value1) {$query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
    echo "<TABLE BORDER = '1'>";
    echo "<TR>";
    echo "<TH>First Name</TH><TH>Last Name</TH><TH>Mail</TH>";
    echo "</TR>";    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
echo "<TR>";
echo "<TD>", $row['fname'], "</TD><TD>",
$row['lname'], "</TD><TD>",
$row['mail'], "</TD>";
echo "</TR>";  
     }
    echo "</TABLE>";}

    else {
        echo "<BR>No Table".
    }

    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

the diffrence from your code is i added a return value of true if its successfully inserted and false if not. and gave that value into $value1.

And if i may .. this code have some serious performace and other problems starting with email often needs more than 20 charaters, and running a create db, create table queries on every run .. etc.

Comment: @Anush-this is exactly what I meant. Thanks again!

Comment: One Problem Though: This error is shown: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ISSET, expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\FormIntoDB\form1.php on line 29. Help?

Comment: yes line 27 should be
if (isset($value1) ) {$query = "SELECT * FROM table1";